# How to bind to selected text using knockout in Select2 ajax

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, jquery-select2

I'm using knockout + select2 and data for one of my dropdowns is lazyily loaded using ajax (select2 supports that).

I need to be able to bind selected text of the dropdown, but can't find a way to do it.

Does anyone know if it's possible at all?

Comment: Here is an example where I'm able to display value, but not text:

http://jsfiddle.net/uE8Vk/

Answer (score 0):

I've had success doing this using the knockoutjs event binding:

HTML:

```
 select2: { minimumInputLength: 3, allowClear: true, query: ajaxQuery }, event: { change: eventHandler }" />
```

JS:

```
self.eventHandler = function (data, event) {

    };
```

in the event object will be a property called added or removed depending on the change that occurred. You can then use this value to update your viewmodel.